# Como generar una excepcion para valores por fuera de una matriz

Tags: python

Soy un estudiante de la carrera de Fisica en Argentina y tenemos una materia la cual es programacion. 
Actualmente estamos trabajando en python con la libreria numpy y en uno de los ejercicios se nos solicito que dado un elemento cualquiera de una matriz sumar los elementos que estan a sus esquinas. 
Yo estuve intentando hacer dicho ejercicio y logre que me genere una matriz al azar junto a un elemento al azar. Sin embargo, a la hora de sumar, por logica es posible que los elementos a sumar esten fuera de la matriz lo cual me tira el error ***IndexError***.
Es por esto que me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma en la que yo pueda generar una excepcion a esos valores que estan fuera de la matriz y les asigne el valor de "0" (asi no me afecta a la suma de los elementos).
En la ultima clase estuvimos viendo debugging y excepciones por lo que me surgio la duda si podria usar los comandos "***try" y "except"*** para realizar dichas excepciones. 
A continuacion, adjunto el programa que estuve haciendo:

```
import numpy as np
malla= np.random.random_integers(1,10,size=(5,5))

comp_i= np.random.random_integers(0,4)
comp_j= np.random.random_integers(0,4)

uprig= (comp_i-1), (comp_j+1)
uplef= (comp_i-1), (comp_j-1)
dorig= (comp_i+1), (comp_j+1)
dolef= (comp_i+1), (comp_j-1)

try:
    malla[uprig]
except IndexError:
    malla[uprig]=0
try:
    malla[uplef]
except IndexError:
    malla[uplef]=0-
try:
    malla[dolef]
except IndexError:
    malla[dolef]=0
try:
    malla[dorig]
except IndexError:
    malla[dorig]=0


suma= malla[uprig]+malla[uplef]+malla[dolef]+malla[dorig]

print(malla)
print()
print(comp_i, comp_j)
print()
print(suma)
```

Aclaro que el programa debe funcionar para cualquier matriz de cualquier dimension simplemente que aqui le asigne una dimension para ir testeando.
Sin embargo, este programa me sigue tirando el mismo error de ***Index Error*** asi que me gustaria saber que alternativa tengo ya que tengo el examen en 2 semanas y me gustaria entender bien como encarar el problema.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo del todo la especificación de tu problema. Parece que tienes una matriz de 5x5, por lo que los índices de la misma han de estar entre 0 y 4. Y sin embargo generas índices al azar entre -1 y 5, por lo que puede darse el caso de que te salga -1 (que estaría fuera de a matriz) o 5 (que también estaría fuera).

La primera cuestión es: ¿no sería mucho más sencillo si los índices que generas al azar están ya dentro del rango? Es decir, haz que estén entre 0 y 4 en lugar de entre -1 y 5. Aunque realmente los generas entre 0 y 4 aquí:

```
comp_i= np.random.random_integers(0,4)
comp_j= np.random.random_integers(0,4)
```

después les sumas y restas 1 aquí:

```
uprig= (comp_i-1), (comp_j+1)
uplef= (comp_i-1), (comp_j-1)
dorig= (comp_i+1), (comp_j+1)
dolef= (comp_i+1), (comp_j-1)
```

lo que causa que puedan pasar a estar entre -1 y 5. Yo cambiaría el trozo anterior por:

```
comp_i= np.random.random_integers(1,3)
comp_j= np.random.random_integers(1,3)
```

y de este modo no se te pueden producir ya excepciones.

Si, por otro lado, por razones que no comprendo, necesitas que los índices estén entre -1 y 5 pero quieres capturar y evitar las excepciones, lo que haces por ejemplo aquí:

```
try:
    malla[uprig]
except IndexError:
    malla[uprig]=0
```

no te servirá, ya que aunque detectas correctamente la excepción en caso de que la esquina buscada no esté, lo que haces en el tratamiento de la excepción de nuevo intenta acceder a `malla[uprig]`, para asignarle  un 0, y ya que ese elemento como sabemos no está, volverá a producir una excepción (un array numpy no "crece automáticamente" asignándole un elemento donde no lo hubiera)

Para este caso lo correcto sería tratar de extraer el valor de ese elemento, y si no existe, extraer 0 en su lugar, pero sin intentar guardarlo en el elemento. Algo así:

```
try:
    uprig_value = malla[uprig]
except IndexError:
    uprig_value = 0
```

Y lógicamente en la expresión final usarías estos valores:

```
suma= uprig_value + uplef_value + dolef_value + dorig_value
```

Comment: Finalmente el ejercicio es para generar excepciones reconocerlas y resolvarlas

Comment: Supongamos que tengo una matriz 5x5 y tengo un numero ubicado en la posicion [2,2] por lo tanto tengo que sumar los numeros que estan en las posiciones [1,1],[1,3],[3,1] y [3,3] (es por este motivo que a "i" y "j" le resto o sumo 1). Como tengo que sumar estos numeros hay casos donde los numeros a sumar van a estar fuera de la matriz (suponiendo que mi numero central esta en [1,1]) por lo que no habria numeros que sumar. Entonces a mi me gustaria a esas posiciones inexistentes tomarlas como "0" para que no afecten a la suma o que python directamente no me los cuente

Comment: @FacuAyala Entiendo, y en base a eso había hecho la segunda parte de mi respuesta ¿no te sirve?

Comment: Me disculpo, si, me sirve. No habia leido la segunda parte para cuando puse el comentario. Muchas Gracias